# Long Polling and applicationDidEnterBackground:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, long-polling

I'm writing a very Simple Chat Application and would like to know how to suspend the long polling selector when the Application enters background.

Currently, I have a Chatroom class (A UIView) which handles the long polling like so:

```
-(void)startPolling
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

- (void) longPoll {
    
    //Poll the Requested URL...
        
    NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataReceived:) 
                           withObject:responseData waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

-(void) dataReceived: (NSData*) data
{    
   //Reload my Tableview etc.. 
}
```

How do I use `applicationDidEnterBackground:` to suspend the longPoll selector until the application comes back to the foreground? Or is this automatically done by the Application Delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request will automatically be suspended. It's not guaranteed that the request will necessarily *succeed* after being resumed, so you'll have to handle errors, but it shouldn't break.

Note that there are probably better ways to write this than using `performSelectorInBackground:`, which always spins up a new hardware thread. For starters, it's probably better to simply loop inside `longPoll` instead of starting a new thread for the new request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you recommend I loop inside the longPoll?

Comment: Possibly just an infinite loop. If you have some condition that would allow you to stop continuously polling (other than existing/suspending the program), you could use that as the condition. Ideally, though, you should use `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` instead of a synchronous request on a background thread.